# Java application running on kubernetes pod is having memory consumption while heap and non-heap is not taking much memory

Tags: java, kubernetes, memory-leaks, jvm, heap-memory

Java application is running on kubernetes pod with memory request of of 3.5Gib and limit of 4.5Gib.   Its `working set size` and is around 4GB and `container cache` is around 1.43Gib and `resident set bytes` is around 2.96GiB. As shown below. This memory is not coming down even when there is no traffic because of this my pods are not downscaling.

Heap and non-heap total memory is 1.76GB and 425 MB. What could be the probable cause of wss or rss memory not coming down? My application is running on java 17 using G1 GC.

I have plotted `jvm_gc_pause_seconds_sum` there i couldn't find any major GC action, can this be GC issue?

[image: WSS, RSS , Cache of container]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried heap dump also there were few unreachable objects and nothing much there.

Comment: Welcome to one of the peculiarities of Java: There is no demalloc meaning that once the JVM has allocated memory, it will NEVER return it to the OS until the JVM shuts down. From what I see, I'd be willing to bet that we are talking of a Spring(Boot) application or an application server: A shitload of classes are loaded during initialization, never to be used again.